# I want to have a choiceset along with a input box of numeric type in adaptive card

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I want to develop an adaptive card that is fusion of columnset & choiceset in adaptivecards.

The context within which I want to use is while doing a checkout of the items in a cart, I want to give an option to the user to increase/decrease the quantity of an item as in the image 
[image]

Comment: Can you please add some code showing what you have already tried?

Comment: You can find cards samples with drop-down menu item here http://adaptivecards.io/samples/#CalendarReminder